# Layout XML inside an empty RelativeLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I have a "Tools.java" that shows "tools.xml" correct? Within this "tools.xml" RelativeLayout have a layout id = @+/contentLayout that is empty.

And I have several other activits "tool1.java", "tools2.java" ... that shows "tool1.xml", "tool2.xml" ...

How to call the class "tool1.java" for example and have it show the "tool1.xml" within the RelativeLayout that is in "tools.xml"

Thanks

Comment: If you need to dynamically inflate them, [`ViewStub`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) might also be an interesting option.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >

<include

    layout="@layout/yourxmlfilename" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I could not, I think I said wrong, check again, I edited the question please